# While hitting the Rest API from Java Getting below 500 Error JSON REQUEST GET MEthod

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

{"message":[{"item":null,"moreinfo":"Error while intiating the transaction"}],"status":"FAILED","statuscode":"500"}
InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=https://xyz/mic/api/check/:P02CA0000010020000, status=500, reason=Internal Server Error}}
500

Below is the Code snippet -

```
` ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
            HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "admin123");
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
            client.register(feature);
            WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
            int respCode =  response.getStatus() ;
            String policyResponse =  response.readEntity(String.class) ;
            System.out.println(policyResponse);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(respCode);
            //Reading the policy search response    

           return policyResponse;

          } catch (Exception e) { 
              System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
              e.printStackTrace(); 
              return e.toString();
          }
```

Here url is - https://xyz/mic/api/check/:P02CA0000010020000

The same is working when i am hitting through post man -

Below is the Postman snaps -

[Post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3b5R.png)
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acRiD.png)

Comment: Just to check: I see a colon in the above URL `.../check/:P...`. Is that correct? Is it also in the Postman URL?

Comment: I believe thats a "sample" URL. You wouldn't want us to hit your service over the internet.
Anyway, when you get a HTTP 500 error it indicates something went wrong on the server side. Can you access the server logs and check the difference in error logs when you hit this rest end-point via postman vs. when you hit it using your client program? Looking at the Server error logs in HTTP 500 scenario would help.

Comment: I update the colon and now i am getting this - @andrewjames

Comment: Unable to do automatic authentication for user : admin, error: Got null response from CAS. please check the URL and the parameters send to CAS server for non interactive login
InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=https://xyz/mic/api/check/P02CA0000010020000, status=403, reason=Forbidden}}
403

Comment: @AG The actual  url is this - https://test/mic/api/check/:var . Here i placed the variable in postman and it worked . What mapping should i update to make it working. This is set to a path variable in postman. I dont have access to server log

Comment: @JRock in that case looks like your client program is doing something slightly different than what "postman" is doing. Can you compare the requests created by PostMan vs. the request created by your program?  Check requestHeaders. I am not sure why you have request-media-type set to application/json when this is a get request and you are using path variable.